# How do I run Interactive PDF files in iPad?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to run Interactive PDF files in iPad using Xcode.

I have successfully run simple PDF file in iPad using Xcode. But when I tried to run interactive PDF file which contains videos then in iPad simulator it skips the videos in the PDF and simply run the PDF.

Please help me out in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult, because most PDF viewers (and engines) just concentrate on the graphical representation. Interactive elements like hyperlinks, javascript and videos are generally not supported.

Unless you find a ready-to-use engine (maybe Adobe has something like that as an SDK?) it will be difficult. There are a lot of video codecs and formats that you'd need to support.